# Why does Eclipse indicate that there are errors in multiple ways even when there are none?

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-errors

This file builds and runs correctly, but the IDE shows multiple error markers in the scroll bar (the little pink boxes) and in the mysterious red bars on the left (no tool tips appear when hovering).

[image: editor view]
[image: problems view]

Is this a bug in Eclipse?  A bad plugin interaction?

W7, Eclipse 4.4.1.  Eclemma, JBoss Tools, MoreTest, Color Theme, and FindBugs installed.

Comment: What does the Problems view show?

Comment: @greg-449 updated to include the error-free problems view

Comment: @courageous anonymous downvoter: "software tools commonly used by programmers;" http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I would go to Project --> Clean --> Clean all projects and then this will rebuild the entire, getting rid of any outdated error markers.

Comment: @ecbrodie this does not make these error markers go away in this case

Answer (score 0):

The red markers could be code coverage indicators (lack of code coverage, to be specific) coming from the EclEmma plugin. Did you recently run your unit tests with the code coverage option? EclEmma, in its default configuration, will leave the coverage markers visible until you manually clear them.

Comment: I uninstalled EclEmma today and the problem persists.